# Unable to Run Testcases Based on Tag in Robot Framework form cmd line

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, robotframework, execution

Today, Suddenly my robot Runner.py was not working. Basically Runner.py contains the command line commands to run my robot testcases based on the tags.
Evreytime when the Runner.py is ran, a requirements.txt file will be executed and all the libraries in it will be installed by python intepreter.

```
cmd="pip install -r Requirements.txt --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --user"
os.system(cmd)
```

And then the testcases are ran by python intepreter using:

```
cmd="robot -i RunNow -d ../Output/Execution_%s -P ../CustomLibrary/  --extension robot ../TestSuite "%(dts)
os.system(cmd)
```

And reports are generated using:

```
cmd="python3 -m robotmetrics -R ExecutionMetrics -I ../Output/Execution_%s --logo  ../../Resources/logo.png  --ignorelib  ['OperatingSystem'] --ignoretype ['for']" %(dts)
os.system(cmd)
```

Where RunNow is the tag i am using in my testcases and TestSuite is my Folder which contains my .robot test files.

Till Yesterday all this commands were working perfectly, but today it was not working, the first error I got is

> > > Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv>=1.11.2->tox==3.0.0->robotframework-jsonlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 4)) (3.0.12)
> > > [ ERROR ] Unexpected error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 83, in _execute
> > > rc = self.main(arguments, **options)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\run.py", line 433, in main
> > > suite = builder.build(*datasources)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\running\builder\builders.py", line 45, in build
> > > suite = parser.parse(structure)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\running\builder\builders.py", line 93, in parse
> > > structure.visit(self)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\parsing\suitestructure.py", line 46, in visit
> > > visitor.visit_directory(self)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\parsing\suitestructure.py", line 165, in visit_directory
> > > child.visit(self)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\parsing\suitestructure.py", line 46, in visit
> > > visitor.visit_directory(self)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\parsing\suitestructure.py", line 165, in visit_directory
> > > child.visit(self)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\parsing\suitestructure.py", line 44, in visit
> > > visitor.visit_file(self)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\running\builder\builders.py", line 99, in visit_file
> > > suite, _ = self._build_suite(structure)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\running\builder\builders.py", line 129, in _build_suite
> > > suite = parser.parse_suite_file(source, defaults)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\running\builder\parsers.py", line 53, in parse_suite_file
> > > return self._build(suite, source, defaults)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\running\builder\parsers.py", line 64, in _build
> > > model = get_model(self._get_source(source), data_only=True,
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\parsing\parser\parser.py", line 45, in get_model
> > > tokens = get_tokens(source, data_only)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\parsing\lexer\lexer.py", line 46, in get_tokens
> > > lexer.input(source)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\parsing\lexer\lexer.py", line 82, in input
> > > for statement in Tokenizer().tokenize(self._read(source),
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\parsing\lexer\tokenizer.py", line 30, in tokenize
> > > tokens = self._tokenize_line(line, lineno, not data_only)
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\parsing\lexer\tokenizer.py", line 49, in _tokenize_line
> > > for value, is_data in splitter(rstrip(line)):
> > > File "c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\robot\parsing\lexer\tokenizer.py", line 68, in _split_from_pipes
> > > _, separator, rest = splitter.split(line, 1)
> > > output.xml file is missing: C:\Users\kbhuva2\git\smartpra-qaautomation\Output\Execution_20200813_053058\output.xml

Then I tried pip freeze > file.txt to get all the libraries installed, uninstalled all of them through the command

```
cmd="pip uninstall -r file.txt"
os.system(cmd)
```

As I ran the runner.py file in the command prompt, it first uninstalled all the libraries in file.txt and installed all the libraries in Requirements.txt and ended up saying

> > > robot is not recognized as internal or external command robotframework, robotmetrics is not recognized as internal or external command robotframework

So after some research I replaced

```
cmd="robot -i RunNow -d ../Output/Execution_%s -P ../CustomLibrary/  --extension robot ../TestSuite "%(dts)
```

to

```
cmd="python3 -m robot -i RunNow -d ../Output/Execution_%s -P ../CustomLibrary/  --extension robot ../TestSuite "%(dts)
```

and

```
cmd="robotmetrics -R ExecutionMetrics -I ../Output/Execution_%s --logo  ../../Resources/logo.png  --ignorelib  ['OperatingSystem'] --ignoretype ['for']" %(dts)
```

to

```
cmd="python3 -m robotmetrics -R ExecutionMetrics -I ../Output/Execution_%s --logo  ../../Resources/logo.png  --ignorelib  ['OperatingSystem'] --ignoretype ['for']" %(dts)
```

Now after making this changes I am not getting robot or robotmetrics is not recognized as internal or external command robotframework but **My Testcases are not picked up with respect to tags, actually it simply executes the command for installing all libraries in Requirements.txt and stops.

After running Runner.py my command prompt looks like:

> > Requirement already satisfied: RESTinstance in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.0.2)
> > Requirement already satisfied: robotframework in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.2.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-metrics in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 3)) (3.1.6)
> > Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-jsonlibrary in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 4)) (0.3.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-jsonvalidator in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 5)) (2.0.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-seleniumlibrary in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 6)) (4.5.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-databaselibrary in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.2.4)
> > Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-dependencylibrary in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 8)) (1.0.0.post1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-pabot in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 9)) (1.8.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-datadriver in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 10)) (0.3.6)
> > Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-csvlib in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 11)) (1.0.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: webdrivermanager in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 12)) (0.8.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: PyMySQL in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 13)) (0.10.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: pypyodbc in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 14)) (1.3.4)
> > Requirement already satisfied: deepdiff in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 15)) (5.0.2)
> > Requirement already satisfied: jsondiff in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 16)) (1.2.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: DateTimeRange in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 17)) (1.0.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: pypika in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 18)) (0.38.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-excellib in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from -r Requirements.txt (line 19)) (2.0.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: tzlocal in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.24.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: rfc3987 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.3.8)
> > Requirement already satisfied: flex in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (6.14.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.6.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (2020.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.16)
> > Requirement already satisfied: jsonpath-ng in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.5.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: strict-rfc3339 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.7)
> > Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.2.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: GenSON in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.2.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from robotframework-metrics->-r Requirements.txt (line 3)) (4.9.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: coverage in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from robotframework-jsonlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 4)) (5.2.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: jsonpath-rw-ext>=0.1.9 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from robotframework-jsonlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.2.2)
> > Requirement already satisfied: tox==3.0.0 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from robotframework-jsonlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 4)) (3.0.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: jsonpath-rw==1.4.0 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from robotframework-jsonlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.4.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: pyjsonselect>=0.2.2 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from robotframework-jsonvalidator->-r Requirements.txt (line 5)) (0.2.2)
> > Requirement already satisfied: objectpath>=0.5 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from robotframework-jsonvalidator->-r Requirements.txt (line 5)) (0.6.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-pythonlibcore>=2.1.0 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from robotframework-seleniumlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 6)) (2.1.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: selenium>=3.141.0 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from robotframework-seleniumlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 6)) (3.141.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from webdrivermanager->-r Requirements.txt (line 12)) (4.48.2)
> > Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from webdrivermanager->-r Requirements.txt (line 12)) (4.5.2)
> > Requirement already satisfied: appdirs in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from webdrivermanager->-r Requirements.txt (line 12)) (1.4.4)
> > Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pypyodbc->-r Requirements.txt (line 14)) (41.2.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: ordered-set>=4.0.1 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from deepdiff->-r Requirements.txt (line 15)) (4.0.2)
> > Requirement already satisfied: typepy[datetime]<2,>=1.0.0 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from DateTimeRange->-r Requirements.txt (line 17)) (1.1.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3,>=2.4.2 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from DateTimeRange->-r Requirements.txt (line 17)) (2.8.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl>=2.4.1 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from robotframework-excellib->-r Requirements.txt (line 19)) (3.0.4)
> > Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (2020.6.20)
> > Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.25.10)
> > Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.10)
> > Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.0.4)
> > Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7.3 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from flex->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.15.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.11 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from flex->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (5.3.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: jsonpointer>=1.7 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from flex->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: click>=3.3 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from flex->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (7.1.2)
> > Requirement already satisfied: validate-email>=1.2 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from flex->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.3)
> > Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jsonpath-ng->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.4.2)
> > Requirement already satisfied: ply in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jsonpath-ng->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.11)
> > Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jsonschema->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.16.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jsonschema->RESTinstance->-r Requirements.txt (line 1)) (19.3.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->robotframework-metrics->-r Requirements.txt (line 3)) (2.0.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: pbr>=1.8 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jsonpath-rw-ext>=0.1.9->robotframework-jsonlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 4)) (5.4.5)
> > Requirement already satisfied: pluggy<1.0,>=0.3.0 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tox==3.0.0->robotframework-jsonlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 4)) (0.13.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv>=1.11.2 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tox==3.0.0->robotframework-jsonlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 4)) (20.0.30)
> > Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.4.17 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tox==3.0.0->robotframework-jsonlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.9.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: mbstrdecoder<2,>=1.0.0 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from typepy[datetime]<2,>=1.0.0->DateTimeRange->-r Requirements.txt (line 17)) (1.0.0)
> > Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from openpyxl>=2.4.1->robotframework-excellib->-r Requirements.txt (line 19)) (1.0.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: jdcal in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from openpyxl>=2.4.1->robotframework-excellib->-r Requirements.txt (line 19)) (1.4.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from virtualenv>=1.11.2->tox==3.0.0->robotframework-jsonlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 4)) (0.3.1)
> > Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in c:\users\kbhuva2\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from virtualenv>=1.11.2->tox==3.0.0->robotframework-jsonlibrary->-r Requirements.txt (line 4)) (3.0.12)

Contents of Requirements.txt is

```
RESTinstance
robotframework
robotframework-metrics
robotframework-jsonlibrary
robotframework-jsonvalidator
robotframework-seleniumlibrary
robotframework-databaselibrary
robotframework-dependencylibrary
robotframework-pabot
robotframework-datadriver
robotframework-csvlib
webdrivermanager
PyMySQL
pypyodbc
deepdiff
jsondiff
DateTimeRange
pypika
robotframework-excellib
```

Please Help on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easy to understand what is going on. When you say:

> Till Yesterday all this commands were working perfectly, but today it was not working, the first error I got is

> > > unexpected error: valueerror: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1) robot

The first thing you need is to identify where that error is coming from. Maybe the omitted lines before the error, could help to do that.

One problem I see in this (strange) way to install and run `robot`, is the fact that you do not set specific versions for the packages. If a new version of a package causes and error, then you may be in the current situation.

Comment: Hi Helio, I pushed my code to bitbucket for pull request and it was merged to the branch, i made a latest pull from the main branch and switched to different branch and from then on this problem started.

Comment: Hi @Helio, I have added my error in the question , please help on this

Comment: The problem was with the robotframework 3.2.1. However i uninstalled this version and installed 3.1.2 of robot framework and set path upto sitepackages ie C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\

And Luckily it worked. Thanks for the support.